# Reversing a char array in C++ causing an error

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am using the following code in order to reverse a char array.  My code as well as the error can be found below.

My code:

```
char * reverseStr(char* s) {
int i=0; //legnth of string
while(s[i]) i++;
char reversed[i];
for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    reversed[j] = s[i-j - 1]; //look at this later
}
return *(reversed);
}
```

The error:

```
        Compiling...
Compile error: your program did not compile correctly:
program.c: In function 'char* reverseStr(char*)':
program.c:18: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'
      --> 17:   }
      --> 18:   return *(reversed);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looking like an issue with const types. http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html

Comment: put the complete code i think the error is in another part of your code

Comment: Why are you returning a character instead of the pointer to char of the reversed string?

Comment: another thing you can't create an array of variable type it must be fixed you can use new operator instead char* reversed=new char[i]; the array length must be known at the compiling time

Comment: You've posted the wrong part of the code - the error is in or around line 45, probably in the call to strcpy.

Comment: Can someone also point out the pointer to local variable issue in an answer?

Comment: `char reversed[i];` ---> Variable Length Array in C++?? i is supposed to be known at Compile time.

Comment: at compile time i=0, i will increase only when you send string to it by calling function at execution time

Comment: @Ahmed safan:: `i` is not `const` mind you. It should not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `i` is not `const`.

```
char reverseStr(char* s) {
int i=0; // --->> NOT CONST
while(s[i]) i++;
char reversed[i];
for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    reversed[j] = s[i-j - 1]; //look at this later
}
return *(reversed);
}
```

`char reversed[i];` ---> Variable Length Array in C++?? `i` is supposed to be known at Compile time.

Answer (score 6):

Your return value and type is wrong.

Furthermore, your declaration of `reversed` is invalid and would leak memory in any case.

Also, calculating the string length instead of using `std::strlen` isn’t recommended and the standard library has the [`std::reverse`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) function to reverse strings.

Comment: : I think rather than causing a memory leak, the declaration `char reversed[i];`should cause an error and not compile, since `i` is not `const`. `VLA`s are not supported by C++ AFAIK.

Comment: @Acme that’s what I meant by “is invalid”. But even with VLA support and a fixed `return` statement this function would leak an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are returning a char instead of a char*, so you are only returning the first letter in the reversed string instead of a string. Which causes your error messages, because you try to treat a char as a char*.

Comment: The `reversed` array is allocated inside the function, so returning a pointer to it would be a bad idea anyway.

Comment: True, he needs to allocate that array with new.

Answer (score 2):

Check the error message:

```
program.c: In function 'int itoa2(int, char*, int)':
program.c:45: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'
```

It clearly tells you what the error is: invalid cast from const char* to char

Answer (score 0):

strcpy receives (char*, const char*) as parameters.However, the return type of your function is char, thus the error appears.
   And char reversed[] is allocated on the stack of the function, please don't use it as a return value.